# Why does appengine uploads all my files everytime?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a small blog that I run on appengine, with around 400 pages (the blog entries), a couple of pictures and so on. 900 files in total, everything is static.

When I make a new blog entry I just have one new html file and maybe one or 2 pictures, but when I deploy to app engine, I see in the log that ALL files are cloned and it takes a lot of time (my internet connection is slow).

Is there a way to tell app engine to clone only the files that have changed ?

Comment: Can you share the output? Normally only files that have changed will be uploaded. The deploy process makes a local copy of all your files first, maybe that is the message you are seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no way currently. To avoid the issue, use a CMS in appengine which could store your pages in Google Cloud Storage.  you then update the individual pages there.

Also, you should probably switch methods, drop appengine and instead host the entire static site in a GCS bucket, then just update the files there as needed.

See
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website